# Get duplicate data of same field from table with compare other field of same table

Tags: php, mysql

[image]

I want to get duplicate partid from different bomid (1 & 2) as per below image.

I have already tried join and having clause but it does not work.

**Desire output**

```
---------
partid
----------
31
```

Comment: do you just need duplicates in partid coulmn ? also please improve your accept ate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT  partID
FROM    myTable
GROUP BY partID
HAVING  COUNT(partID) > 1
```

**[SEE HERE for a little demo (*though different fieldnames*)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/febc4/1)**

Comment: Thanks John, Your query help me to resolve my problem.I have make my query using your answer.My query is SELECT partID
FROM bom_details
WHERE bomid
IN ( 1, 2 ) 
GROUP BY partID
HAVING COUNT( partID ) >1

Comment: Thanks for your kind help,Your example is really helpful.